# Jinja Trimming Whitespace Around Single-Line If Statement

Tags: templates, jinja2, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I would like to create a Jinja template along these lines:

```
Some list:
    - foo
    {% if a %}- bar: a{% endif %}
    {% if b %}- baz: b{% endif %}
    - quux
```

That renders like the "Rendering Goals" below.

However, I can't find a combination of `-` and `+` modifiers that does what I want in all cases without resorting to putting the `{% if ... %}` and `{% endif %}` tags on separate lines.

Specifically, I don't want any blank lines or extra whitespace when `a` and/or `b` are `False`.

The best I can do is this:

```
Some list:
    - foo
    {%- if a %}
    - bar: a
    {%- endif %}
    {%- if b %}
    - baz: b
    {%- endif %}
    - quux
```

Is it possible to create a more compact template than that?

Rendering Goals:

- `{ 'a': True, 'b': True }`:

```
Some list:
    - foo
    - bar: a
    - baz: b
    - quux
```

- `{ 'a': True, 'b': False }`:

```
Some list:
    - foo
    - bar: a
    - quux
```

- `{ 'a': False, 'b': True }`:

```
Some list:
    - foo
    - baz: b
    - quux
```

- `{ 'a': False, 'b': False }`:

```
Some list:
    - foo
    - quux
```